# Writing to HDFS could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hdfs

I have 3 data nodes running, while running a job i am getting the following given below error ,

> java.io.IOException: File /user/ashsshar/olhcache/loaderMap9b663bd9 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1325)

This error mainly comes when our DataNode instances have ran out of space or if DataNodes are not running.
I tried restarting the DataNodes but still getting the same error.

dfsadmin -reports  at my cluster nodes clearly shows a lots of space is available.

I am not sure why this is happending.

Comment: Do you have the right file permissions on this file?

Comment: Make sure the `dfs.datanode.address` port address is open. I had a similar error happen to me and it turned out that out of the several ports I needed to open, I neglected `50010`.

Comment: Thanks @MarkW, that was my mistake too. Care to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1.Stop all Hadoop daemons

```
for x in `cd /etc/init.d ; ls hadoop*` ; do sudo service $x stop ; done
```

2.Remove all files from `/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/name`

```
Eg: devan@Devan-PC:~$ sudo rm -r /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/
```

3.Format Namenode

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs namenode -format
```

4.Start all Hadoop daemons

```
for x in `cd /etc/init.d ; ls hadoop*` ; do sudo service $x start ; done
```

[Stop All Hadoop Service](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_27_3.html)

Comment: I run into the same problem, would you please explain why should I do this to solve the problem and if the data would be lost?

Comment: This ain't no solution. -1

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue, I was running very low on disk space. Freeing up disk solved it.

Comment: Thanks for this! My one-node system was misconfigured to run from an incorrect partition and it simply didn't have the capcity in it to hold yet another file.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check whether your DataNode is running,use the command:`jps`.
2. If it is **not running** wait sometime and retry.
3. If it is **running**, I think you have to re-format your DataNode.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do when this happens is that I go to *tmp/hadoop-username/dfs/* directory and manually delete the *data* and *name* folders (assuming you are running in a Linux environment).

Then format the dfs by calling *bin/hadoop namenode -format* (make sure that you answer with a capital *Y* when you are asked whether you want to format; if you are not asked, then re-run the command again).

You can then start hadoop again by calling *bin/start-all.sh*

Comment: This is the only solution to the OP's question that worked for me. I was trying to follow the example in [link](http://blog.tundramonkey.com/2013/02/24/setting-up-hadoop-on-osx-mountain-lion) on my Macbook osx mountain lion 10.8.5, but could not see the datanode being generated after start-all.sh, until I deleted the data and name and namesecondary folders as mentioned above. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I solved it as bellow:

1. Find where are your datanode and namenode metadata/data saved; if you cannot find it, simply do this command on mac to find it (there are located in a folder called "tmp")

   **find /usr/local/Cellar/ -name "tmp";**

   find command is like this: find <"directory"> -name <"any string clue for that directory or file">
2. After finding that file, cd into it.
   /usr/local/Cellar//hadoop/hdfs/tmp

   then cd to dfs

   then using -ls command see that data and name directories are located there.
3. Using remove command, remove them both:

   **rm -R data .      and      rm -R name**
4. Go to bin folder and end everything if you already have not done it:

   **sbin/end-dfs.sh**
5. Exit from the server or localhost.
6. Log into the server again: ssh <"server name">
7. start the dfs:

   **sbin/start-dfs.sh**
8. Format the namenode for being sure:

   **bin/hdfs namenode -format**
9. you can now use hdfs commands to upload your data into dfs and run MapReduce jobs.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this issue was resolved by opening the firewall port on 50010 on the datanodes.

Comment: can you be more specific , which protocole should I use , and the name of the programme ...

Comment: Thanks. I got the same error message as the OP, while all my datanodes are healthy. It turned out that the master could not connect to those datanodes on port 50010.

Answer (score 0):

**Very Simple fix for the same issue on Windows 8.1**
I used Windows 8.1 OS and Hadoop 2.7.2, Did the following things to overcome this issue.

1. When I started the hdfs namenode -format, I noticed there is a lock in my directory. please refer the figure below.
   [image: HadoopNameNode]
2. Once I deleted the full folder as shown below, and again I did the **hdfs namenode -format.**
   [image: Folder location] 
   [image: Full Folder Delete]
3. After performing above two steps, I could successfully place my required files in HDFS system. I used **start-all.cmd** command to start yarn and namenode.

Comment: could please explain more your steps

Answer (score 0):

In my case the dfs.datanode.du.reserved in the hdfs-site.xml was too large as well as the name node giving out the private ip address of the data node so it could not route properly. The solution to the private ip was to switch the docker container to host network and place the hostname in the host properties of the config files.

This goes over other possibilities
[Stack Question on replication issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015864/hadoop-be-replicated-to-0-nodes-instead-of-minreplication-1-there-are-1/36310025)

Answer (score 0):

The answers saying to open port numbered `50010` *might* only apply to an older version of Hadoop. I'm using Hadoop version `3.3.4` and the port you should open to fix this error is `9866`. You need to open this port on all of the Hadoop dataNodes.
Here's a code snippet you can use in RHEL 8:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port 9866/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```