# No valid local directories in property: mapred.local.dir

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I am running the VM in pseudo mode.
Due to some resource related issues (Name Node in safe mode, not able to leave) I had to format and restart the namenode of my Cloudera 4.x. I didn't have any other choice.
I used the steps provided here:

[Writing to HDFS could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571584/writing-to-hdfs-could-only-be-replicated-to-0-nodes-instead-of-minreplication)

After that I am able to properly use get/put command in hdfs which means I have read/write permission.
Now, when I try to submit the job, I am getting following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main"org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): java.io.IOException: No valid local directories in property: mapred.local.dir
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.submitJob(JobTracker.java:3491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.submitJob(JobTracker.java:3459)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server$WritableRpcInvoker.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:898)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1689)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1687)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No valid local directories in property: mapred.local.dir
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getLocalPath(Configuration.java:1678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getLocalPath(JobConf.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.<init>(JobInProgress.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.submitJob(JobTracker.java:3489)
    ... 13 more
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy10.submitJob(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:973)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:896)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:561)
    at clustering.mapreduce.KMeansClusteringJob.main(KMeansClusteringJob.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)**
```

When I searched for above exception I found multiple links stating that mapred.local.dir should be properly defined and if not set then hadoop.tmp.dir is used.
I explicitly set mapred.local.dir in mapred-site.xml and given full permission to the default folder (/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache).
The problem still persists.

Can someone please help in solving the issue?
Regards

Comment: My Bad :-(.. Didn't give proper permission to the local directory.

How to mark the query closed?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't give proper permission to the local directory -- Marking as Community wiki as answer was provided in the comments